# Mobile site showing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media

I have a website https://checkitscheaper.com/ but problem is it is showing mobile version when opening  in IE. Any solution? I have tried this many times with different meta tags and CSS but it didn't work anymore.

Comment: What version of IE? IE < 9 does not support media queries without a polyfill, is this possibly the reason?

Comment: Problem exists in IE10 too.

Comment: How big is your CSS file? IE stops reading after 4095 selectors.

Comment: or set media screen with `min-width` not `max-width` aka mobile-first

Comment: srsly, this isnt normal stylesheet, its SOOO big - (https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcheckitscheaper.com%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=cs)